# tabBarVisible: false does not work on a stackNavigation child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Info project
"react-navigation": "^3.6.0",
"expo": "^32.0.0"

I have a TabNavigator, inside this I have redirections to children, which are StackNavigator. The problem is that within the children, I can not hide the tabNavigator with tabBarVisible: false

THE PARENT (TabNavigator)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Home, Search, Add, Follow, Profile } from '../screens';
import HomeNavigator from './Home';
import SearchNavigator from './Search';

const config = {
    headerMode: 'none',
    tabBarPosition: 'top'
};

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: HomeNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            title: 'Home',
        })
    }
};

const Authenticated = createBottomTabNavigator(screens, config);

export default createAppContainer(Authenticated);
```

THE CHILDREN (StackNavigator)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Home, Profile } from '../screens';
import { Posts, Comments } from '../screens/screensHome';

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        }
    },
    Comments: {
        screen: Comments
    }
};

const HomeNavigation = createStackNavigator(screens, config);

export default createAppContainer(HomeNavigation);
```

THE VIEW (width navigationOptions)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Comments extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarVisible: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>I'm the Comments component</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I leave here the code of the app

https://snack.expo.io/@ricarquico/clone-instagram

in short I want to hide this http://prntscr.com/n6hw68

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you tried this.
https://snack.expo.io/Sk7Go1WRM

**Issue on Github:** https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/issues/19

```
StackA.navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>{
let { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
   let navigationOptions = {};
   if (routeName === 'Comments') {
      navigationOptions.tabBarVisible = false;
   }
    return navigationOptions;
}
```

Comment: Hello, this does not work for me, I leave here the code of the app https://snack.expo.io/@ricarquico/clone-instagram in short I want to hide this http://prntscr.com/n6hw68